# Azure VM suddenly unavailable

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine

I've had an Azure VM running fine for years but all of a sudden I can't access it anymore. Not through RDP nor through http.
Nothing changed on my side and Microsoft only gives phone support for 230€/month. What to do?

Comment: Does everything look OK in the Portal?  Its running, endpoints valid etc?

Comment: Yep everything  normal in the portal

Comment: We had a difficult issue so we signed up for email support (~£20 a month) and they spent a ton of time on the issue (like 2 weeks).  Definitely got our monies worth.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has corrupted?  The only two things I can think of are: try connecting over Powershell to see if it will respond; You could pull it down from storage and launch the console locally to see what is going on?  Azure as you may know doesn't offer a console access.  The only other option is to rebuild it assuming you have backups etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally put the money down and got it up again. The advice on the phone was to upgrade from A2 to A3 processor/memory specs. This would force the VM to go to another machine, ruling out problems with the hardware / NIC. This worked but was quite expensive. They will get back to me next week with the exact problem report.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cost of an A3 machine, you should be able to upgrade from A3 back to an A2. The chances of it landing in the same physical server are slim to none.

Comment: that what was recommended to me and I'll do that in off hours